# Clean up history in Gitlab Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Is there an easy way to remove all the previous pipelines runned in Gitlab?

[image]

I would like to clean up this section, but didn't find any options through the interface.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

You can only delete individual pipelines one by one in the UI.

To do bulk deletions, you can use the [pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#delete-a-pipeline) to programmatically list and delete pipelines.

In Python (with the [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library) it might look something like this:

```py
import gitlab
project_id = 1234
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.example.com', private_token='My token')
project = gl.projects.get(project_id)
for pipeline in project.pipelines.list(iterator=True):
    pipeline.delete()
```

Comment: I don't get why GitLab is not creating a cron schedule option to remove old pipelines.

Comment: How do you delete 1 pipeline in the history using the UI?

Comment: @tzg when you are viewing the pipeline (like where you can see the job graph), there is a delete button in the top-right corner, but IIRC the pipeline must be in a complete state (e.g., failed, skipped/cancelled, success) for the button to show up in the UI. Deleting pipelines requires **owner** [role permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#gitlab-cicd-permissions).

Comment: Ok, permissions must be my issue because I'm not seeing the button.  Thanks!